# lme4 error: boundary (singular) fit: see ?isSingular

Tags: r, lme4

I am trying to run `lme4` package in R. I have 10 Lines in total with four plants for each line in each of the two replications. But some of the plants died and there are some missing values. `Weight` is the response variable. Here are some lines from the data:

```
Line    Rep Weight  PLANT
Line 1  1   NA  1
Line 1  1   NA  2
Line 1  1   NA  3
Line 1  1   NA  4
Line 2  1   26  1
Line 2  1   26  2
Line 2  1   26  3
Line 2  1   27  4
Line 1  2   26  1
Line 1  2   28  2
Line 1  2   26  3
Line 1  2   25  4
Line 2  2   24  1
Line 2  2   26  2
Line 2  2   25  3
Line 2  2   NA  4
```

I want to run linear mixed model using `lme4` package so I tried running:

```
lme4 <- lmer(Weight ~ 1 + (1|Rep:Plant), data=Data)
```

But I got an error:

> boundary (singular) fit: see ?isSingular

```
> dput(Data)
structure(list(Line = c("Line 1", "Line 1", "Line 1", "Line 1", 
"Line 2", "Line 2", "Line 2", "Line 2", "Line 1", "Line 1", "Line 1", 
"Line 1", "Line 2", "Line 2", "Line 2", "Line 2"), Rep = c(1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2), Weight = c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA, 26, 26, 26, 27, 26, 28, 26, 25, 24, 26, 25, NA), 
    PLANT = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4)), row.names = c(NA, 
-16L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

I am using it for the first time and I am not sure about the error. I will appreciate any help!

Comment: Hi, I have added dput(Data) output in the post. Thank you!

Comment: I think I did not clear that I am getting the error when I use the entire dataset with 536 entries in total. I am not getting the error with this subset.

Comment: Yes that makes sense now.. So it happens when the model is a bit too complex. I see that you have PLANT and Rep as numbers, these means fitting them as continuous variables..

Comment: This means you expect the mean weight to increase from PLANT 1 to 4.. which is not true i guess. Can you try this, Data$PLANT = factor(Data$PLANT) ; Data$Rep = factor(Data$Rep); and fit this model first , lmer(Weight ~ 1 + (1|Rep) + (1|Plant), data=Data)

Comment: Yes, I do not want these as continuous variables. After trying PLANT and Rep as factors, I still got the same error "boundary (singular) fit: see ?isSingular" after running the model you suggested.

Comment: I still got the same error. I can attach the data here or can email you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207074/discussion-between-stupidwolf-and-jessica).

Comment: see also https://bbolker.github.io/mixedmodels-misc/glmmFAQ.html#singular-models-random-effect-variances-estimated-as-zero-or-correlations-estimated-as---1

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Your model did fit, but it generated that warning because your random effects are very small. You can read more about this in [this post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/378939/dealing-with-singular-fit-in-mixed-models) or [the help page](https://rdrr.io/cran/lme4/man/isSingular.html)

Let us look at your data:

```
ggplot(Data,aes(x=PLANT,y=Weight,col=Rep)) + geom_jitter() + geom_boxplot(alpha=0.2) + facet_wrap(~Rep)
```

[image]

The effects of `PLANT` and in combination with Rep is extremely small. Let's look at the fitted model:

```
fit = lmer(Weight ~ 1 + (1|PLANT:Rep),data=Data)
boundary (singular) fit: see ?isSingular
ranef(fit)
$`PLANT:Rep`
    (Intercept)
1:1           0
1:2           0
2:1           0
2:2           0
3:1           0
3:2           0
4:1           0
4:2           0
```

This is exactly what happened. So we can try to account for some other effects and we still see very small coefficients:

```
fit = lmer(Weight ~ Line + (1|Rep:PLANT),data=Data)
ranef(fit)
$`Rep:PLANT`
      (Intercept)
1:1  1.397563e-19
1:2  2.811371e-19
1:3  8.112169e-20
1:4  1.813251e-19
2:1 -1.725964e-19
2:2 -2.463986e-20
2:3 -2.027357e-19
2:4 -2.833681e-19
```

The takehome message is, there's no really systematic effect coming from PLANT, so you don't need to specify a highly complicated model, do something like:

```
fit = lmer(Weight ~ Line + (1|Rep),data=Data)
```

The data in case anyone is interested:

```
Data = structure(list(Line = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 
12L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 34L, 34L, 34L, 34L, 45L, 45L, 45L, 45L, 
56L, 56L, 56L, 56L, 65L, 65L, 65L, 65L, 66L, 66L, 66L, 66L, 67L, 
67L, 67L, 67L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 
9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 13L, 
13L, 13L, 13L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 16L, 16L, 
16L, 16L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 66L, 66L, 66L, 66L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 
17L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 
20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 24L, 
24L, 24L, 24L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 26L, 26L, 
26L, 26L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 
28L, 29L, 29L, 29L, 29L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 
67L, 67L, 67L, 67L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 33L, 
33L, 33L, 33L, 35L, 35L, 35L, 35L, 36L, 36L, 36L, 36L, 37L, 37L, 
37L, 37L, 38L, 38L, 38L, 38L, 39L, 39L, 39L, 39L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 
40L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 
41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 43L, 
43L, 43L, 43L, 44L, 44L, 44L, 44L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 46L, 46L, 
46L, 46L, 47L, 47L, 47L, 47L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 48L, 48L, 48L, 
48L, 49L, 49L, 49L, 49L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 
50L, 50L, 50L, 50L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 52L, 52L, 52L, 52L, 41L, 
41L, 41L, 41L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 46L, 46L, 46L, 46L, 11L, 11L, 
11L, 11L, 33L, 33L, 33L, 33L, 53L, 53L, 53L, 53L, 54L, 54L, 54L, 
54L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 38L, 38L, 38L, 38L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
37L, 37L, 37L, 37L, 55L, 55L, 55L, 55L, 57L, 57L, 57L, 57L, 44L, 
44L, 44L, 44L, 58L, 58L, 58L, 58L, 59L, 59L, 59L, 59L, 12L, 12L, 
12L, 12L, 47L, 47L, 47L, 47L, 48L, 48L, 48L, 48L, 60L, 60L, 60L, 
60L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 
26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 61L, 61L, 61L, 61L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 59L, 
59L, 59L, 59L, 52L, 52L, 52L, 52L, 29L, 29L, 29L, 29L, 62L, 62L, 
62L, 62L, 63L, 63L, 63L, 63L, 54L, 54L, 54L, 54L, 55L, 55L, 55L, 
55L, 53L, 53L, 53L, 53L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 50L, 50L, 50L, 50L, 
64L, 64L, 64L, 64L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 58L, 58L, 58L, 58L, 16L, 
16L, 16L, 16L, 57L, 57L, 57L, 57L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 63L, 63L, 
63L, 63L, 64L, 64L, 64L, 64L, 61L, 61L, 61L, 61L, 36L, 36L, 36L, 
36L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 39L, 39L, 39L, 39L, 
45L, 45L, 45L, 45L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 42L, 
42L, 42L, 42L, 43L, 43L, 43L, 43L, 65L, 65L, 65L, 65L, 49L, 49L, 
49L, 49L, 56L, 56L, 56L, 56L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 62L, 62L, 62L, 
62L, 35L, 35L, 35L, 35L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 60L, 60L, 60L, 60L, 
34L, 34L, 34L, 34L), .Label = c("Line1", "Line10", "Line11", 
"Line12", "Line13", "Line14", "Line15", "Line16", "Line17", "Line18", 
"Line19", "Line2", "Line20", "Line21", "Line22", "Line23", "Line24", 
"Line25", "Line26", "Line27", "Line28", "Line29", "Line3", "Line30", 
"Line31", "Line32", "Line33", "Line34", "Line35", "Line36", "Line37", 
"Line38", "Line39", "Line4", "Line40", "Line41", "Line42", "Line43", 
"Line44", "Line45", "Line46", "Line47", "Line48", "Line49", "Line5", 
"Line50", "Line51", "Line52", "Line53", "Line54", "Line55", "Line56", 
"Line57", "Line58", "Line59", "Line6", "Line60", "Line61", "Line62", 
"Line63", "Line64", "Line65", "Line66", "Line67", "Line7", "Line8", 
"Line9"), class = "factor"), Rep = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("1", "2"), class = "factor"), Weight = c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA, 26L, 26L, 26L, 27L, NA, NA, NA, NA, 26L, 28L, 26L, 
25L, 22L, 17L, 20L, 20L, 28L, 20L, 27L, 26L, 22L, 25L, 21L, 25L, 
18L, 18L, 19L, 18L, 24L, 28L, 23L, 30L, 29L, 25L, 26L, 27L, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, 29L, 30L, 29L, 30L, NA, NA, NA, NA, 33L, NA, NA, 
NA, 21L, 23L, 18L, 23L, 32L, 29L, 30L, 30L, 18L, 19L, 21L, 21L, 
25L, 25L, 25L, 26L, 26L, 27L, NA, NA, 29L, 29L, 27L, 29L, 26L, 
NA, NA, NA, 26L, 20L, 23L, 27L, NA, NA, NA, NA, 32L, 32L, 30L, 
30L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 19L, 22L, 21L, 22L, 22L, 24L, 23L, 23L, 25L, 
20L, 25L, NA, NA, 27L, 26L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 30L, 28L, 
NA, NA, 25L, 26L, 27L, 26L, NA, NA, NA, NA, 20L, 19L, NA, NA, 
19L, 27L, 26L, 29L, 26L, 29L, 31L, 29L, 25L, 25L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 
25L, 26L, 26L, 25L, 24L, 24L, 28L, 22L, 26L, 24L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 
26L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 26L, 24L, 24L, 24L, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, 30L, 30L, 30L, 31L, 24L, 25L, 28L, 22L, 28L, 
31L, 30L, NA, 31L, 30L, 29L, 25L, 25L, 22L, 24L, 20L, 30L, 30L, 
30L, 29L, 26L, 32L, 28L, 29L, 20L, 15L, 15L, 11L, 25L, 24L, 24L, 
24L, 26L, 29L, 31L, 30L, 24L, 28L, 20L, 22L, 29L, 26L, 26L, 28L, 
27L, 27L, 27L, 26L, 21L, 22L, 21L, NA, 28L, 29L, 24L, 24L, 28L, 
29L, 28L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 27L, 29L, NA, NA, NA, NA, 22L, 26L, 
21L, 21L, 26L, 30L, 28L, 30L, 27L, 26L, 28L, 26L, 25L, 25L, 26L, 
26L, 27L, 26L, 23L, 29L, NA, NA, NA, NA, 27L, 23L, 29L, 23L, 
28L, 29L, 28L, 26L, 20L, NA, NA, NA, 28L, 23L, 26L, 21L, 28L, 
26L, 26L, 29L, 20L, 27L, 20L, 26L, 29L, 26L, 28L, 28L, 30L, 27L, 
NA, NA, 26L, 21L, 26L, 25L, 27L, 26L, 27L, 24L, 25L, 20L, 21L, 
20L, 25L, 25L, 31L, 24L, 29L, 28L, 31L, 27L, 25L, 28L, 26L, 26L, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, 24L, 25L, 23L, 27L, 20L, 26L, 25L, 25L, 29L, 
28L, 29L, 29L, 26L, 27L, 25L, 28L, NA, NA, NA, NA, 26L, 28L, 
NA, NA, 21L, 20L, 31L, 25L, 31L, 28L, 30L, 29L, 23L, 25L, 24L, 
28L, 25L, 22L, 25L, 25L, 28L, 29L, 28L, 29L, 26L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 
29L, 27L, NA, NA, 26L, 29L, 29L, 30L, 25L, 24L, 25L, 24L, 28L, 
25L, 29L, 28L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 28L, 30L, 27L, 27L, 26L, 25L, 
25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 28L, 25L, 25L, 30L, 28L, 25L, 22L, 24L, 25L, 
24L, NA, NA, NA, NA, 5L, 7L, 4L, 5L, 21L, 20L, 22L, 24L, 25L, 
27L, 25L, 28L, 32L, 31L, NA, NA, 19L, 26L, 20L, NA, 26L, 26L, 
30L, 25L, 28L, 31L, 30L, 26L, 5L, 8L, 4L, 8L, 25L, 25L, 28L, 
25L, 28L, 28L, 27L, 26L, 30L, 27L, 27L, 24L, 32L, 29L, 31L, 25L, 
30L, 30L, 27L, 28L, 16L, 20L, 16L, 21L, 25L, 22L, 25L, 20L, 24L, 
25L, 18L, 25L, 25L, 26L, 29L, 29L, 21L, 20L, 22L, 21L, 19L, 22L, 
19L, 21L, 28L, 25L, 26L, 24L, 28L, 26L, 24L, 25L, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, 25L, NA, NA, NA, 23L, 21L, 19L, 23L, 25L, 24L, 25L, NA, 22L, 
30L, 29L, 26L, 25L, 25L, 24L, 24L), PLANT = structure(c(1L, 2L, 
3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 
3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 
3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 
3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 
3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 
3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 
3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 
3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 
3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 
3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 
3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 
3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 
3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 
3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 
3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 
3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 
3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 
3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 
3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 
3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 
3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 
3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 
3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 
3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 
3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 
3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 
3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 
3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 
3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 
3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 
3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 
3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 
3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 
3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L), .Label = c("1", "2", "3", "4"), class = "factor"), 
    X = structure(c(4L, 2L, 5L, 6L, 4L, 2L, 5L, 6L, 4L, 2L, 5L, 
    6L, 4L, 2L, 5L, 6L, 4L, 2L, 5L, 6L, 4L, 2L, 5L, 6L, 4L, 2L, 
    5L, 6L, 4L, 2L, 5L, 6L, 4L, 2L, 5L, 6L, 4L, 2L, 5L, 6L, 4L, 
    2L, 5L, 6L, 4L, 2L, 5L, 6L, 4L, 2L, 5L, 6L, 4L, 2L, 5L, 6L, 
    4L, 2L, 5L, 6L, 4L, 2L, 5L, 6L, 4L, 2L, 5L, 6L, 4L, 2L, 5L, 
    6L, 4L, 2L, 5L, 6L, 4L, 2L, 5L, 6L, 4L, 2L, 5L, 6L, 4L, 2L, 
    5L, 6L, 3L, 7L, 8L, 1L, 3L, 7L, 8L, 1L, 3L, 7L, 8L, 1L, 3L, 
    7L, 8L, 1L, 3L, 7L, 8L, 1L, 3L, 7L, 8L, 1L, 3L, 7L, 8L, 1L, 
    3L, 7L, 8L, 1L, 3L, 7L, 8L, 1L, 3L, 7L, 8L, 1L, 3L, 7L, 8L, 
    1L, 3L, 7L, 8L, 1L, 3L, 7L, 8L, 1L, 3L, 7L, 8L, 1L, 3L, 7L, 
    8L, 1L, 3L, 7L, 8L, 1L, 3L, 7L, 8L, 1L, 3L, 7L, 8L, 1L, 3L, 
    7L, 8L, 1L, 3L, 7L, 8L, 1L, 3L, 7L, 8L, 1L, 3L, 7L, 8L, 1L, 
    4L, 2L, 5L, 6L, 4L, 2L, 5L, 6L, 4L, 2L, 5L, 6L, 4L, 2L, 5L, 
    6L, 4L, 2L, 5L, 6L, 4L, 2L, 5L, 6L, 4L, 2L, 5L, 6L, 4L, 2L, 
    5L, 6L, 4L, 2L, 5L, 6L, 4L, 2L, 5L, 6L, 4L, 2L, 5L, 6L, 4L, 
    2L, 5L, 6L, 4L, 2L, 5L, 6L, 4L, 2L, 5L, 6L, 4L, 2L, 5L, 6L, 
    4L, 2L, 5L, 6L, 4L, 2L, 5L, 6L, 4L, 2L, 5L, 6L, 4L, 2L, 5L, 
    6L, 4L, 2L, 5L, 6L, 4L, 2L, 5L, 6L, 4L, 2L, 5L, 6L, 4L, 2L, 
    5L, 6L, 3L, 7L, 8L, 1L, 3L, 7L, 8L, 1L, 3L, 7L, 8L, 1L, 3L, 
    7L, 8L, 1L, 3L, 7L, 8L, 1L, 3L, 7L, 8L, 1L, 3L, 7L, 8L, 1L, 
    3L, 7L, 8L, 1L, 3L, 7L, 8L, 1L, 3L, 7L, 8L, 1L, 3L, 7L, 8L, 
    1L, 3L, 7L, 8L, 1L, 3L, 7L, 8L, 1L, 3L, 7L, 8L, 1L, 3L, 7L, 
    8L, 1L, 3L, 7L, 8L, 1L, 3L, 7L, 8L, 1L, 3L, 7L, 8L, 1L, 3L, 
    7L, 8L, 1L, 3L, 7L, 8L, 1L, 3L, 7L, 8L, 1L, 3L, 7L, 8L, 1L, 
    3L, 7L, 8L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 5L, 6L, 4L, 2L, 5L, 6L, 4L, 2L, 5L, 
    6L, 4L, 2L, 5L, 6L, 4L, 2L, 5L, 6L, 4L, 2L, 5L, 6L, 4L, 2L, 
    5L, 6L, 4L, 2L, 5L, 6L, 4L, 2L, 5L, 6L, 4L, 2L, 5L, 6L, 4L, 
    2L, 5L, 6L, 4L, 2L, 5L, 6L, 4L, 2L, 5L, 6L, 4L, 2L, 5L, 6L, 
    4L, 2L, 5L, 6L, 4L, 2L, 5L, 6L, 4L, 2L, 5L, 6L, 4L, 2L, 5L, 
    6L, 4L, 2L, 5L, 6L, 4L, 2L, 5L, 6L, 4L, 2L, 5L, 6L, 4L, 2L, 
    5L, 6L, 3L, 7L, 8L, 1L, 3L, 7L, 8L, 1L, 3L, 7L, 8L, 1L, 3L, 
    7L, 8L, 1L, 3L, 7L, 8L, 1L, 3L, 7L, 8L, 1L, 3L, 7L, 8L, 1L, 
    3L, 7L, 8L, 1L, 3L, 7L, 8L, 1L, 3L, 7L, 8L, 1L, 3L, 7L, 8L, 
    1L, 3L, 7L, 8L, 1L, 3L, 7L, 8L, 1L, 3L, 7L, 8L, 1L, 3L, 7L, 
    8L, 1L, 3L, 7L, 8L, 1L, 3L, 7L, 8L, 1L, 3L, 7L, 8L, 1L, 3L, 
    7L, 8L, 1L, 3L, 7L, 8L, 1L, 3L, 7L, 8L, 1L, 3L, 7L, 8L, 1L
    ), .Label = c("24", "12", "21", "11", "13", "14", "22", "23"
    ), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, -536L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: FWIW the link above is a 'man page' (help page to normal non-Unix-geezers), not a vignette, although arguably there should be a whole vignette about this situation ... although I've already written an enormous amount about this, I'm not sure how much more I have to say ...

Comment: sure let's change. is there anything else beyond man vs vignette?

Comment: Hi @StupidWolf, your answer in this post highly helped me to continue with my modelling but I found some issues that I would like to know if I can have your opinion. Thanks. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71386051/beta-values-and-the-confint-of-a-linear-model?noredirect=1#comment126285951_71386051